Choosing a bounty winner
I asked a question, place a bounty, provided the clarifications, and got two magnificent answers. Alas, I feel like I don't have the expertise needed to choose the bounty winner. What do I do now ? How can I "summon the gods" (no pun intended) for guidance? I am willing to put the rest of my points as the bounty if that would help. What else can I do?

I think you can offer multiple bounties. Award one, then offer another and award that to the other answer. I don't think you can split the bounty between two answers though.

I would suggest waiting until the last minute, then award it to the highest-voted answer

@mikeazo This has the problem that any following bounty has to be higher than the previous ones, so no equi-bounty for both.

@PaŭloEbermann, I had no idea. Good to know.

Unfortunately, there's no way to split a bounty.  One solution is to accept one answer and award a bounty to the other.  Another solution is to award a second bounty, but be aware that the second bounty costs more.
Other than that, all I can suggest is to enjoy your good fortune. ;-)
